# duplicate output of two objects of a subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, output

im a noobie and im trying to understand a specific output im getting.
I use Eclipse Mars release 4.5

So I have the follow code:

```
public class SuperClass{

    protected String query;

    public SuperClass(){}

    public SuperClass(String query)
    {
        this.query=query;
        System.out.println("Super Class");
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return query="value";
    }
}
```

And also the following subclass of the previous class:

```
public class SubClass extends SuperClass
{
    public SubClass()
    {
        System.out.println("Sub Class");
    }

}
```

Now when I try to initialize two different objects of the subclass I get a confusing output, as follows:

```
public class Main
```

{

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    SubClass test1=new SubClass();
    SubClass test2=new SubClass();

    System.out.println(test1);  
}
}

 **Output:**
   Sub Class
   Sub Class
   value
```

What is confusing to me is that even though I printed only the object "test1", im getting duplicate output as if I printed both of the objects.

Any help?

Comment: What do you think `System.out.println("Sub Class");` does? What do you think `new SubClass();` does?

Comment: System.out.println("Sub Class"); prints the string Sub Class and new SubClass(); create a new object of the subclass class

Comment: And what happens when you instantiate a class? What gets called?

Comment: The constructor

Comment: So the constructor gets called, and `System.out.println("Sub Class");` is in the constructor, and you create two instances. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are printing "Sub Class" in Subclass constructor.

System.out.println("Sub Class");